# Find points within a radius in ArcGis 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, geoprocessing

I have a feature service which is created from a view in a geospatial geodatabase.
I want to retrieve all the point/geometries than fall within a specific distance.
I am using arcgis 10.2
I know that i could do it using the JS api like in this  [Example](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/query_buffer.html).
However I would prefer to have geo-processing task that would retrieve the a point and calculate which point fall within a buffer of a specific radius around this point.
The problem is that I cannot find a tool to give me the points within the buffer.
Is there any simple way to do that ?

In other words my inputs are

1. the radius
2. A feature class which in my case in a view in a geodatabase
3. a point around which I want to find the nearby points.

And my output should be all the nearby points around the input point

Answer (score 2):

you can do this with the tool called "[select layer by location](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000072000000)", which runs after you create a layer with "make feature layer". One of the options for spatial relationship, i.e. WITHIN_A_DISTANCE , will do the job.

Comment: Thanks. How time consuming and inefficient could the make feature layer tool be, for many large amount of data

Comment: Dear @radouxju. I would appreciate your opinion about which of the two ways, referred in my question could be more efficient? I think using the "make feature layer" could be inefficient since it would take time to convert my table view (hosted as service) in a temp feature layer so as to be used in turn for querying from the "Select Layer By location".

Comment: a feature layer is not so inefficient : it is a kind of pointer to your data. The other geo-processing task combination that you could use (without layer) is creating a buffer, then spatial join then select. Each step would write new data, so for selection with geoprocessing tasks I recommend using layer. If you want to improve effciency, using arcpy.da.searchcursor could help (but I am not sure).

Comment: Thanks @radouxju. However i am not speaking about the feature layer itself.i think that the conversion of a geodatabase table view into a feature layer is inefficient.

Comment: I followed your advice with "select layer by location". As I can see, in my result, The correct points are graphically selected. When I right click in arcmap and press open so as to see the the contents of my layer, I can see that it contains all the features of my input feature layer. The row of the selected only features are aqua color  (selected). How can I tell my model take as output only the selected rows? @radouxju

Comment: the layer can be directly used as input for further processing in the model (only the selection will be processed). If this is to be your last step and you need a feature class, you can use arcpy.CopyFeatures_management